# errors while updating kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, repository

when i try to update by using "sudo apt update"i get this errors

```
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease.
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu jammy Release
404 Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]. Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release
404 Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80].
```

and

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
```

can anyone help with this?

Comment: You are using unsupported repositories, and you have mistyped `i386` somewhere.

Comment: You're clearly trying to use Kali as a general purpose linux platform. It's not. **You shouldn't be using Kali**, says [Kali themselves](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/).

Comment: You're adding third-party repositories, which you **really** shouldn't do. So, this is 100% a duplicate of (replace "deluge" with the software you installed from third-party repos):

Comment: seriously, who tells beginners they should be using Kali, and who tells them to add Ubuntu packages for multimedia libraries? Like, these are two things that Kali says, very clearly, you should not do, on its own website.

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate to connect to the apt repository seems to have expired and/or does not belong to the version you or the os needs to connect to. remove the existing PPA, so in your case,

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/java
```

and then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try finding the exact resource you need to download from the Kali's repository.

If you still need to add the repository anyway, then confirm if the repository you're trying to add has the package you're looking for. In your case, go [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/source/) and check if your package is available in Sources.gz file. If they're not, you've come to a dead end. [Maybe because the latest source in there is for bionic beaver(Ubuntu 18) and they're rightfully not maintaining it anymore.]

If you nevertheless need to use binaries of ubuntu on Kali, (hey, linux is for you, and for freedom, use the latest repositories to do that.)

Comment: Hello stackoverflow community. I have a poor english background so please take my answer with a pinch of salt, as most likely I could have not conveyed what I wanted in the Answer. Also, @user506156, please feel free to ask for any further clarifications.